# How to configure a relationship as a Set in a PersistentModel?

Tags: swift, swift-data

The new SwiftData framework runs successfully when using an `Array` but produces a fatal error when using a `Set` in a `@Relationship`. Why?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    @Relationship(inverse: \Parent.items) var parent: Parent?
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

@Model final public class Parent {
    var items: Set<Item>
}
```

> SwiftData/SchemaCoreData.swift:907: Fatal error: Failed to link relationship to destination entity 'Set because it could not be found in the model: (<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x6000033085a0>), name items, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Parent, renamingIdentifier items, validation predicates (
> ), warnings (
> ), versionHashModifier (null)
> userInfo {
> }, destination entity (null), inverseRelationship (null), minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1

Tested in Xcode beta 15.0.

Answer (score 0):

As
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/array-vs-set-differences-explained/
pointed out
You can use a Set instead of an Array when the order of items is not important, or when you need to ensure that an item only appears once. Remember both are value types, where array can hold values twice and a Set never contains duplicates.

It looks to me as You want to have the Item Set in a one to many relation?
Ios 17,
You can make I standard SwiftData Project. Rename the standard to IItem and
Insert the two models underneath. Should kind of work.

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
//    @Relationship(inverse: \Parent.items) var tags: [Parent]?
   //@Relationship(inverse: \Parent.items) var parent: Parent?
    @Relationship(inverse: \Parent.transactions)
       var parent: Parent?
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

@Model final public class Parent {
    var items: MySet
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
        var transactions: [Item] = []
    
    init(items: MySet, transactions: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
        self.transactions = transactions
    }
}


typealias MySet = Set<Int>
struct Cell: Codable {
    var classesEntieres : MySet = []
    var classesDemiA : MySet = []
    var classesDemiB : MySet = []
    var m : Int = -1
    var s : Int = -1
    var a : Int = -1
}
```